# Special characters in chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have to write in Spanish and I have OSX version of Minecraft. I had a problem with some special characters when playing multiplayer. Everybody is writing these characters and I can see them clearly, but the key on my keyboard to insert this ticks over the vocals does nothing, so when I press the vocal key it's written normal.

The characters I'm talking about are: `áéíóú`. I have no problem with `ñ`.

I tried to put the game in Spanish, or turning `Forcing Unicode Font` to `ON`, but no luck. Anyone knows what to do to fix this?

Comment: Does the keyboard input affect that? I know if you choose US (International) the `'` key waits for the next letter to add the accent. i.e. `'` and `a` = `á`

Comment: @Ben Yes, that is the standard way to enter accents in Spanish. It works on the rest of applications and games, and it's currently set to `ES (International)`, as always was

Comment: The language in Minecraft has nothing to offer?

Comment: The Language button inside Minecraft only let you select language and the option `Forcing Unicode Font` as said in the question, and I already tried different languages having the same problem in every of them

Comment: Have you tried asking other players how they write them?

Comment: @Ender Yes. They simply write them as usual. The keys work for them naturally (First `\`` and then the vocal). However, I'm the only one playing from OSX.

Comment: Im on OSX too... Minecraft is a little strange with it as for eg. The F1-F9 keys can only be used with CTRL and CMD does nothing. Have you tried holding CTRL while doing this? Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Sk4llsRPG That's different. In OSX the F keys have special functions by default. You can override this (and use the standard F function of windows) holding the `fn` key or disabling this features in the settings

Comment: @SysDragon Ok. Im currently away from my Mac at the moment and have never known that existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [very long-standing bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-42171) in Minecraft on Mac OS X with so-called "[dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)" like Spanish keyboards' <kbd>´</kbd> and <kbd>`</kbd> keys. (Your <kbd>ñ</kbd> works fine because it produces `ñ` using a single key instead of two.) Unfortunately, Mojang keeps thinking they have Minecraft's dead key handling fixed, but their Mac expertise seems to be insufficient and they don't seem to realise that fixing these keys on Windows doesn't automatically fix them on Mac OS X due to differences in how each operating system handles dead keys.

The most solid (but least quick) solution is to [make noise on Mojang's bugtracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-42171). Until Mojang fixes this on their end, there is no way to type these keys on a Mac OS X keyboard layout that uses dead keys.

A workaround is to [manually design a new keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/a/282889) that doesn't use dead keys to type these letters, instead overwriting some of your other keys with keys dedicated to all the other accented characters (like the dedicated <kbd>ñ</kbd> key already is). You can do that using the Ukulele program in that link to create a custom layout. You'd have to sacrifice some keys, and which are up to you (I don't use Spanish keyboards and couldn't give useful advice for keys to replace), but the nice thing about Ukulele is that its graphical interface makes it easy to test and tweak your layout until it works for you.

Once you've created your layout and put the file in the right place (see Ukulele's instructions), you can use Mac OS X's **Language & Text** control panel to select your new keyboard layout as an keyboard option that you can easily switch to before launching Minecraft, then switch back to your regular Spanish layout when you're done. To make switching painless, make sure you have **Show Input menu in menu bar** selected in that control panel, so you can easily switch layouts from the OS X menu bar.

Answer (score -1):

if you are on mac press option then press any letter

Comment: Could you be a little more clear, and give explicit instructions on what you're trying to say? Some users may be less advanced than others, and require more information.